# Arduino monitor working together with PHP

Tags: php, arduino

I've finally got all the sensors working, sending data into text files, etc., but I've got a problem with PHP. I can connect to Arduino with a PHP-based website. I can turn an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) on or off. But I can't do that while I'm reading data from Arduino.

I'm using the command:

```
cat /dev/ttyACM0 > data.txt
```

Everything is working fine, but when I'm trying to use a PHP script, I'm getting connection errors.

If I'm not using the command "cat", I can normally use a PHP site, but I cannot see the sensors data.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about calling `exec()`? Also, it is always a good idea not to tell anyone the code you are using so they do not get distracted by it from making a good answer...

Comment: Hey! It's not about code. I can use simple code to read temperature in Arduino monitor, and while I'm reading, Arduino's processor is busy and I cannot do anything with PHP. PHP script need Arduino's processor to be free, but I don't know how I can read and write in same time. That's my problem.

Comment: Use a single cronjob to do the single-task Arduino stuff, and from PHP you only send commands to the cronjobs queue and read back results.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question where you're getting the connection errors.
If the arduino or linux is throwing the errors, most likely the PHP script is locking the data.txt file.
Make sure you open the file in read mode only

```
fopen("data.txt", "r");
```

If it's the browser, there might be a problem in the way you read the file.
If PHP enters a loop reading the file, the connection times out, as it never reaches "End Of File".
You could try creating a PHP script that reads part of the file, like the last 50 lines or so (or "tail -n 50 data.txt"), and another page with a periodical ajax call to that PHP script.

For more help you should really post your most relevant PHP code